# DirectorySearcher.ClientTimeout - Search timed out or really 0 results?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I maintain a C# program which needs to check whether thousands of Active Directory accounts are still in existence & if they are enabled or not.  Recently, I've found that my program was hanging while querying the directory for an account.  Fortunately, I've just discovered the [DirectorySearcher.ClientTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.clienttimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) property (which I hadn't been setting, meaning that the search goes on indefinitely).

The one problem that I see with using this property is that, if the search hangs while looking up an account that happens to actually exist, the DirectorySearcher.FindOne() method will return 0 results.  As you can imagine, that's a problem since at runtime, I don't know whether the search failed or if the account really wasn't found.

Does anyone know if there's another property that gets set in the object that I can use to see if the search aborted?  Is there any difference between a result set from an aborted search versus one that really contains zero results?

Here's my method:

```
public static string UserExists(string username, Log log)
    {
        string accountStatus;

        if (username.Split('\\').Length != 2)
            return "Invalid ID,Invalid ID";
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string[] parts = username.Split('\\');
                domain = parts[0];
                ScopeDN = "DC=" + domain + ",DC=contoso,DC=com";
                DirectoryEntry de = GetDirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ScopeDN);
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
                ds.SearchRoot = de;
                ds.ClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";

                SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();

                if (result == null)
                    accountStatus = "Does Not Exist,Account Does Not Exist";
                else
                {
                    int UAC = (int)result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];

                    bool enabled = !Convert.ToBoolean(UAC & 0x00002);
                    if (enabled)
                        accountStatus = "Exists,Account is Enabled";
                    else
                        accountStatus = "Exists,Account is Disabled";
                }

                return accountStatus;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.exception(LogLevel._ERROR, e, false);
                return "Exception,Exception";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following optimizations:

- Dispose DirectoryEntry
- Dispose DirectorySearcher
- Create and cache a connection to RootDse object before querying users. In this case all AD queries will use one single cached connection to AD, which significantly increases performance.

For example

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://contoso.com/RootDSE");
entry.RefreshCache();
// making user search and other AD work with domain contoso.com here
entry.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is a great optimization!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no difference. One thing you could do is retry a couple times before assuming it is missing. Its a matter of confidence. One failure may not give high enough confidence.  But 2 or 3 might.  Does that help you?

Comment: I think that's probably the only workaround available.  I hadn't thought of that, thanks!